# Request in cUrl works on CLI - but fails in GuzzleHTTP

Tags: php, curl, guzzle, http-status-code-400

I am able to successfully execute a cUrl command like the following (api key removed):

```
curl --request POST 'http://api.url.example/api/inquiries' \
--header 'User-Agent: GuzzleHttp' \
--header 'Host: api.url.example' \
--header 'Api-Key: API-KEY' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
--data-raw '{
    "AgentID": null,
    "Message": "test"
}'
```

However, when I attempt to construct the same request in GuzzleHTTP - I get back:

`Client error: POST http://api.url.example/api/inquiries resulted in a 400 Bad Request response: {"Code":400,"Message":"Unknown error."}`

I have seen other posts with similar claims - but following their resolutions has not brought me any success.

Here is the GuzzleHTTP request which is throwing the 400 error. The `getHeaders` function is returning an associative array, and the `getBody` function is returning a json string (calling `json_encode` on an associative array)

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

try {
    $rsp = $client->post(
        $this->LEAD_URL,
        [
            'headers' => $this->getHeaders(),
            'body'    => $this->getBody()
        ]
    );
} catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e) {
    throw new Exception('Unable to connect to' + $this->LEAD_URL, 400, $e);
}
```

I have confirmed using MiddleWare that the headers being generated by Guzzle are the same as those listed above in the CLI cUrl request.

Any ideas what could be wrong? Ideas for other details that I could investigate to debug?

<3

Comment: It sounds like your request is not what you think (or want) to be sent.  The easiest way to compare curl to Guzzle, is to enable the debugging request parameter within either your request, or within your Guzzle client instantiation.  http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#debug  `$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['debug' => true,]);` or `$response=$client->post($url, ['debug' => true,]);`